# Validate and add class to past, current & future dates with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this snippet to validate if the data-date attribute is newer / equal / older than current date to assign respective class. However, the code only valid to 1 - 9 only, else it will considered older than current date.

Please refer to these codes

```
$(function() {
  var date = new Date(),
  currentDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();
  $(".grid-item").each(function() {
    var specifiedDate = $(this).data('date');
    if (specifiedDate == currentDate) {
      $(this).addClass('today');
    } else if (currentDate > specifiedDate) {
      $(this).addClass('past');
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('future');
    }
  });
});
```

Please refer to this working fiddle. Thank you for your help!

https://jsfiddle.net/sandalkoyak/jrnvzrfu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. You need to parse date string using **Date.parse()** method which returns milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC or NaN if the string is unrecognised or, in some cases, contains illegal date values (e.g. 2015-02-31).

```
$(function() {
    var date = new Date(),
    currentDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getDate();
    currentDate=Date.parse(currentDate);
    $(".grid-item").each(function() {
       var specifiedDate = $(this).data('date');
       specifiedDate=Date.parse(specifiedDate);
       if (specifiedDate == currentDate) {
         $(this).addClass('today');
       }else if (currentDate > specifiedDate) {
         $(this).addClass('past');
       }else {
         $(this).addClass('future');
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: Sweet! Thank you sir!